# android - How to use getContentResolver().query for multiple columns?

Tags: android, sql

Im using the next code to get info about a row in the db by the _ID -

```
Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(PlacesContract.Places.CONTENT_URI, null,PlacesContract.Places._ID + " = " + id, null, null);
```

Now i'm trying to use this query in order to check if a item is already exists in the db, and i want the check will also ignore case sensitive.

So i understand that i need to use spme where this segment - ? COLLATE NOCASE.

And i guess that the row i want to check will be like this -

```
String [] projection = {PlacesContract.Favourites.NAME, PlacesContract.Favourites.ADDRESS};
```

and i know that somewhere i nedd to chek if each one is equal to a term, but what i don't understand how should i apply it into the query.

```
Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)
```

so if anyone can help me understand it - it will be great 
Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

OK. It goes like this: (example for a simple contacts query)

```
String[] PROJECTION = { ContactsContract.Data._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE };
String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'" + " AND "
                            + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'" + " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = '"
                            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN + "'";
```

Instead of '1' of the other values in the SELECTION, you can add selectionArgs accordingly.